# How can I add constraints to an ADO.NET Entity?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ado.net-entity-data-model, unique-constraint

I know how to mark a group of fields as primary key in ADO.NET entities but i haven't found a way to declare unique constraints or check constraints.

Is this feature missing on the designer or on the framework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Support for unique keys/constraints does not exist in ADO.NET Entities in v4.0, see the answer to "[one-to-one association on a foreign key with unique constraint](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/adonetefx/thread/a2faede2-a582-4626-b8bc-47d099cdecd1)", where Diego B Vega says:

> I know for sure we haven't added
>   support for unique keys other than
>   primary keys in 4.0.

He does, however, provide a possible workaround/hack (which comes with all the normal caveats):

> As you are probably aware of, it is
>   often possible to “lie” to Entity
>   Framework and tell it in the SSDL, for
>   instance, that some unique key is the
>   primary key. I reckon this would work
>   very well if the actual primary key is
>   an surrogate key (i.e. an IDENTITY
>   column that was added for this
>   purpose) and you don’t even have to
>   map it in the model.