# Is it possible to create an association between two normal fields in Entity Framework, thereby ignoring the primary key?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following situation between these three tables:

[image]

Before I start explaining what I'm trying to accomplish here, let me clarify three things:

1. I drew the model on EntityFramework, but this is actually the database view. Just assume that the fields type match between tables;
2. I know that this database model sucks. But changing it is out of question. I know that it would make my life easier.
3. I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and .Net 3.5 on this project. But I'm accepting solutions based on Visual Studio 2010 and .Net 4.0 as well.

So, as I tried to demonstrate on the picture above, in this project that I'm working on I got these 3 tables. One of then, **TransactionLine**, associates a file to a transaction line, that is part of a full transaction.

Now, what I'm trying to associate here is **TransactionLine** and **File**. However, **TransactionLine** doens't have *FileId* field from the **File** table. The fields *FileNumber* and *FileType* from this table stand for an composite key on **File**. And indeed, **File**'s *FileNumber* and *FileType* never repeat. They could be the primary key, but then again, I can't touch the database structure.

I try to associate **TransactionLine** and **File** by creanting an *Association* of One To Many From **File** to **TransactionLine**. After that, I select the *Association* and change to the *Mapping Details* screen, then I select *Map's to* ***TransactionLine***.

The data that he askes me to fill on the model screen are:

- **File**.*FileId*;
- **TransactionLine**.*TransactionId*;
- **TransactionLine**.*FileNumber*;
- **TransactionLine**.*FileType*,

All of the **TransactionLine** scalar properties are set by theirs corresponding database fields, which are of the same name. But when I'm going to specify the linkage with **File** table, the only scalar field that I can specify there is *FileId*, which I don't have on the **TransactionLine** table.

I also tried to set **File**'s *FileNumber* and *FileType* scalar properties entity key flag to true, and *FileId* entity flag to false, but with no success, since the program warns me that database *FileId* is a primary key but is not set like one on the entity.

Is it possible to link **TransactionLine** *FileNumber* and *FileType* with **File**? Is there any workaround for this situation?

Special Note: *FileId* is indeed the primary key for **File**. Others tables link with it by this field. The **TransactionLine** here is an exception to the common sense rule. :(

Comment: Is there a unique constraint in the database on the File table for the FileNumber and FileType fields?

Comment: This isn't my area, so hopefully someone else can provide better information.  I found this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963829/how-can-i-add-constraints-to-an-ado-net-entity/1979093#1979093), and googled the referenced thread (it's in google's cache). Short answer seems to be a tentative yes, you could trick EF by modifying the SSDL, but I don't think this works for you because you mentioned there are already other relationships to File that use FileId, so if you change the "primary key" of File in the SSDL, then you'll break those relationships.

Comment: There is a Unique Index for them.

Comment: Yeah, we considered changing the "primary key" in the EF model, but the issue with breaking the other relationships keeps us from using that solution :(

Comment: You say you can't modify the database structure...how about adding a new table?  You could add a new table (let's call it FileReference) that has FileNumber and FileType as the primary key and have your TransactionLine table link to that.  You could also put a foreign key constraint on FileReference pointing to those two fields on the File table (good thing you already have a unique index), making a 1-to-1 relationship between File and FileReference.  I know...it's an ugly suggestion.

Comment: This could work, but the tables we can create MUST have only one field in the primary key(actually they are created with two fields.. Code(varchar(8)) and Name(varchar(50)) and this is arbitrary(this doesn't come from our company, but we have to put up with these rules). :(

We tried to do this with an entity that maps only __FileNumber__ and __FileType__ from the File table, but the EF complains that wee didn't map the __FileId__ field

Comment: This isn't correct data modeling, but is it possible for you to make File.FileNumber plus File.FileType a foreign key referencing TransactionLine?

EF would more properly consider TransactionLine to be an association rather than a separate entity, since it's just a join table.  However, that doesn't solve your problem, since the association will still complain about not referencing the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We archieved our goal :D.

Thanks to **Dr. Wily's Apprentice** for giving us a tip about the solution.

Here is what we did:

[image]

1. We created a view, named VIEWFILEEXTRA, with just the fields we’d like to use in the association;
2. After that, we created an entity based on this view, named FileExtra;
3. Map FileExtra to VIEWFILEEXTRA, if not done yet;
4. Change FileNumber and FileType from FileExtra Entity Key flag to true;
5. Delete FileNumber and FileType scalar properties from File;
6. Create an 1 on 1 association between file and FileExtra;
7. Set the scalar properties in the association mapping to point to File’s database fields FileNumber and FileType;
8. Create an 1 to Many association between FileExtra and TransactionLine;
9. Point the association mapping to TransactionLine, and set the fields.

And that’s it. Thank you very much for your attention and tips :D.